# How to use an Exponential Backoff strategy with Apache httpclient?

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

The [docs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/httpclient-cache/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/cache/ExponentialBackOffSchedulingStrategy.html) specify a class of ExponentialBackOffSchedulingStrategy but it doesn't seem to exist in version 4.5.

Also, didn't find anything that explains HOW to use it.

Anyone used something like this before?

Answer (score 2):

`ExponentialBackOffSchedulingStrategy` works on cached entries, that's why it can only be used with a `CachingClient`. I don't think it can be used to implement an exponential backoff retry mechanism on failing requests.

I would implement a simple exponential backoff strategy along these lines:

```java
class MyExponentialBackoffRetryHandler extends HttpRequestRetryHandler {
  public MyExponentialBackoffRetryHandler(int maxNumRetries, int backOffRate, int initialExpiry, int maxExpiry) {
  } 
 boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
   if (executionCount == maxNumRetries) {
     return false;
   }else {
     long nextBackOffDelay = initialExpiry * Math.pow(backOffRate, executionCount - 
1)
     long delay = Math.min(maxExpiry, nextBackOffDelay)
     Thread.sleep(delay);
     return true;
   } 

}
}
```

Also, in order to trigger a retry, you will need to add a response interceptor that throws an `IOException`, e.g :

```java
class MyResponseInterceptor extends HttpResponseInterceptor {
  void process(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
    if (response.getStatusLine.getStatusCode == 503) {
        throw new IOException("Please retry")
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, you can build the HTTP client instance, as follow:

```java
HttpClientBuilder
    .create()
    .setRetryHandler(new MyExponentialBackoffRetryHandler(...))
    .addInterceptorFirst(new MyResponseInterceptor())
    .build()
```

You can easily test the client by sending a request to `https://httpstat.us/503`

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Apache HTTP Client 4.5.x using Maven packages like this (Grails Maven dependency syntax):

```
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1"
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.3"
```

You'll need add another jar to get these classes, like this:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache:4.5.1'
```

See https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/download.html

Then you can wire it up something like this:

```
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.*;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.cache.*;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;

 CloseableHttpClient createClient() {
     CachingHttpClientBuilder hcb = new CachingHttpClientBuilder();
     CacheConfig cc = CacheConfig.DEFAULT;
     ExponentialBackOffSchedulingStrategy ebo = new ExponentialBackOffSchedulingStrategy(cc);
     hcb.setSchedulingStrategy(ebo);
     CloseableHttpClient hc = hcb.build();
     return hc;
 }

 // You'll need to replace the URL below with something that returns a 5xx error
 CloseableHttpClient client = createClient();
 HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/throwsServerError");
 for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
     CloseableHttpResponse response =  client.execute(request);
     println new Date().toString() + " " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
 }
```

Comment: by default it retries immediately, then in 6s then in powers of 10 of 6s, until it exhausts at 6 loops.